# Using @JmsListener with logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

I'm following a guide on using Spring JMS using the JmsListener annotation at the method level.  I think it is working but since I can't debug my breakpoint set in that method or log4j logging doesn't work, or not even a simple System.out.println(), I'm not 100% sure that destination is hitting.

```
@Component
public class JmsEmailServiceConsumer {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private final JmsEmailService jmsEmailService;

    @Autowired
    public JmsEmailServiceConsumer(JmsEmailService jmsEmailService){
        this.jmsEmailService = jmsEmailService;
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "simple.queue")
    public void receiveEmailData(EmailData emailData) {
        jmsEmailService.sendEmail(emailData);
    }
}
```

Pretty simple task.  All I'm trying to do is create a JMS queue to handle the generating of emails.  This process makes a call to the Service, jmsEmailService, which determines via calls to DAOs to select a list of email addresses to send emails.  If none are found, no email is sent.  Now I am testing locally and I don't have an email server up and running but I want to verify if the calls to the DAOs are working.  If they are then I can proceed with committing in the code and get QA to test the email process.

I did it this way because of a blog I found that really removes the bulk of dealing with JMS.  As you can see, all I needed to do was annotate the receiveEmailData method with JmsListener and provide a destination which has already been setup in the Producer class as:

```
private static final String SIMPLE_QUEUE = "simple.queue";

@Autowired
public JmsEmailProducerImpl(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
    this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
}

@Override
public void sendEmail(EmailData emailData) {
    //EmailData emailData = new EmailData(userId, person, company, roleKind, isRemoved);
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(SIMPLE_QUEUE, emailData);
}
```

Pretty easy right?  That's what I thought.  For reference, here's the website I am looking at:

http://xpadro.blogspot.com/2015/04/configure-spring-jms-application-with.html

Any thoughts?  I can place a breakpoint at the line in the producer class which works, but once the jmsTemplate fires off the convertAndSend method, no breakpoint in the consumer class, System.out.println() or log4j logging works.  I do see this in my broker logging:

```
2015-10-26 00:02:34,804 DEBUG   org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue::expireMessages:905    queue://simple.queue expiring messages ..
2015-10-26 00:02:34,804 DEBUG org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue::expireMessages:911   queue://simple.queue expiring messages done.
2015-10-26 00:02:34,804 DEBUG org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue::doPageInForDispatch:1874   queue://simple.queue, subscriptions=0, memory=0%, size=2, pending=0 toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 2, pagedInPendingDispatch.size 2, enqueueCount: 2, dequeueCount: 0, memUsage:48394
```

Comment: Turn on debug logging for `org.springframework.jms` to see activity in the consumer. If your pojo is not called, it implies the container is not running or it's listening to the wrong queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the nudge Gary!  I had a block of settings for org.springframework in my log4j properties but the jms logging didn't appear until I added it for org.springframework.jms.  I did a bit of analyzing with and without my code and saw that the console and file output remained the same.

So in the end, what I was missing that the author of that blog didn't explain is I needed to add the @EnableJms annotation to my JMSConfiguration class and I needed to add the following to the same class:

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
            new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

I'm assuming that Spring Boot adds the necessary plumbing to your configuration class automagically and that is one thing I didn't do.  Once I did this, the breakpoints worked fine.

It's interesting how there are so many ways to skin a cat in Spring and I could have easily stuck with using MessageListeners and overriding the onMessage method, but I wanted to try out using the JmsListener annotation since it's cleaner code.  If I want to add a new JMS queue, all I need to do is create a POJO and add the @JmsListener annotation to the method that will receive the message from the producer.